# Expected time of a process

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Consider the following function, which describes the fraction of evaporated substance, over time
$$
f(t)=1-e^{-a t^2}
$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I am asked to deduce the expected time of evaporation, at any point in the substance.

First, I interpreted this as the time it takes for half of the substance to evaporate, which corresponds to the median time $t_{1/2}$, given by solving
$$
f(t_{1/2})=0.5\Leftrightarrow t_{1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{\log(2)}{a}}.
$$
However, I am told the answer should be
$$
t_E=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
$$
but I do not really see how I can calculate this from the expression of $f$, given it's a sigmoid approaching $1$. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I have noticed that, with $f'(t)=2at e^{-a t^2}$, we have
$$
t_E=\int_0^\infty t f'(t)\,dt=2a\int_0^\infty t^2 e^{-a t^2}\,dt=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.
$$
Is this what they meant?

Comment: I think so. In probability theory language, $f(t)$ is the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of the random time $\tau$ of evaporation: $\mathbb P(\tau\le t)=f(t)\,.$ The PDF (probability density function) is then $f'(t)$ and the expected evaporation time is your last formula.